# How to access local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha after git lfs call?

Tags: git, hook, stdin

In a pre-push hook, I have to make sure Git LFS is set properly:

```
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```

However, i want to then access the information that tells me the local branch and sha information. For example:

```
IFS = ' '
while read local_ref local_sha
do
   * do some stuff *
done
```

However, it seems that calling git lfs wipes this data and so i can't access it. Any ideas?

Comment: Store the required information to environment variables before running lfs?

Comment: But how to get the data, store it, and put it back so git lfs runs as before?

Comment: So it seems i may have to:
1. Read and store the data locally.
2. Write the data backn out as it was.

so how to do #2? Or to somehow take a copy of the data that is there and leave it intact.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can store the data and then pass it to your commands. Note that is for bash:

```
stdin_input=`cat`
echo "$stdin_input" | git lfs pre-push "$1" "$2"

echo "$stdin_input" | while read local_ref local_sha
do
   * do something *
done
```